# Julia programs, execution procedure

Tags: julia

I have a couple of julia programs running in a cluster of 64 processors.
I want to know why if I launch a julia-program like:

```
$ julia main.jl
```

when I see the output of the htop I get 15 processes like this:

```
PID USER PRI NI VIRT RES SHR S CPU MEM TIME        COMMAND
21389 me 20 0 845M 413 12692S 0.0 0.1 TIME-ELAPSED julia main.jl
```

Is this something intrinsic to julia to optimize the main.jl script?

Comment: What system are you on? Is htop showing threads?

Comment: > uname -a Linux thorin 3.7.10-1.1-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 28 15:06:29 UTC 2013 (82d3f21) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

According to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268680/how-can-i-monitor-the-active-thread-count-of-a-process-jvm-on-linux] The number of threads that I have is 16.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your question is why the julia processes all end up on one node instead of across your cluster?

I think you are looking for the ClusterManager features: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/index.html

Comment: Not exactly, the issue is why I am getting 16 processes when I just launched 1, are they executing something? can I get rid of them? My first attempt is to run one single program at one cpu, I haven't enabled yet the parallel stuff.